# How to find a initial solution?

Tags: calculus

[image: Need help to find an initial solution]

I am thinking of solving x first, but I can't solve x, can I?

Please help.

Comment: Can you give some context?  There are also so many variables here, $x$, $y$, $u$, and $w$ - along with the function $F$.

Comment: Hi, Michael Burr, there are only two variables x and y.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I think you can. See that

$$\frac{27}{4}x^4+9x^3=\frac{9}{4}(3x^4+4x^3)=\frac94 w$$

Comment: Yes, Arnaldo. I can see that. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, Amaldo. I got the answer u=9(3x^4+6x^2 y^2+4x^3)/4